# Are naturism-related questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are the questions about **naturism** on topic here?

Naturism is often associated with sunbathing, which isn't a very activity (although being outdoor), but it includes also walking and swimming. But fishing doesn't involve very intensive movement, and is on topic anyway...

If naturism should be generally on-topic, which aspects of it should be on-topic in detail? Let's take geocaching. Even the questions about equipment and software are on-topic here, though some of them would be good candidates for more technical sites. Should we then allow also questions about legal aspects of naturism? Or about naturist clubs/communities?

**edit**

Naturism questions are actually on topic on Travel.SE. So what kind of questions would better fit here than there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturism), naturism is

> Naturism or nudism is a cultural and political movement practising, advocating and defending social nudity in private and in public. It may also refer to a lifestyle based on personal, family and/or social nudism.

and *per se*, doesn't necessarily relates directly to the great outdoors and therefor TGO SE.

The same is true for many other topics. Gadget questions related to the great outdoors are welcomed as much as any naturism questions related to the great outdoors.

Of course some questions could be off-topic. *e.g.*

- Where can I find a naturism public pool in city X?

I believe most outdoor questions are welcomed as long as they relate to an outdoor activity.

I suggest that if anyone have such questions to simply ask it. Thus far, TGO does not have much, if any, naturism questions.

Comment: As I understand, question about swimming pool would be off-topic because swimming-pools are off-topic here (would belong rather to Travel), but a questions about naturist lake or beach would be on-topic?

Comment: Yes; that's my take on it anyway. :) If it's a naturist resort with a beach, probably it is also off topic because it is not related to the great outdoors.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm concerned, a question on-topic here is on-topic regardless of the quantity of clothing worn. If a question is about enjoying the outdoors as such, it doesn't matter if it's connected to naturism.  Just make sure that it is otherwise on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I'd need to see a few questions to get a better sense of it.  But I *think* that questions about doing regular outdoor activities (hiking, rock climbing, etc) naked would be on topic.

... I would recommend that you phrase them carefully so they remain in good taste.  But we could address those issues as they come up.  :)